# Convert SQL query to work in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to convert `SQL` query to work in `MS-Access`, is there any suggested way? thank you

```
SELECT        
  colldet.college,    
  COUNT(DISTINCT manuscript.p_name) AS A,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s_p = 'منجز' THEN p_name END) AS B,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s_p = 'منجز منشور' THEN p_name END) AS C, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s_p = 'مخطط' THEN p_name END) AS D
FROM manuscript 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN colldet 
ON manuscript.coll_name = colldet.college
GROUP BY colldet.college
```

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables. Use IIf() instead of CASE. I doubt the DISTINCT syntax will work. Will probably need nested SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As June7 notes, Access doesn't support COUNT DISTINCT so you'll need to make things distinct before counting.  Also as June7 suggests use Iif() instead of CASE. This is a guess:

```
SELECT Q.College,
COUNT(Q.A1) AS A,
COUNT(Q.B1) AS B,
COUNT(Q.C1) AS C,
COUNT(Q.D1) AS D
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT colldet.college,
    manuscript.p_name AS A1,
    IIF(s_p = 'منجز',p_name,Null) AS B1,
    IIF(s_p = 'منجز منشور',p_name,Null) AS C1,
    IIF(s_p = 'مخطط',p_name,Null) AS D1
    FROM manuscript
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN colldet
    ON  manuscript.coll_name = colldet.college)
AS Q
GROUP BY Q.college
```

Comment: Thank you,there are some problems, `DISTINCT ` not work and all fields have similar count values

Comment: Sorry, I was misunderstanding your CASE statements.  See if my edit is better.

Comment: Sorry, i have a small problem with the current edit, `DISTINCT`  not work

Comment: Does SELECT DISTINCT colldet.college,
    manuscript.p_name AS A1,
    IIF(s_p = 'منجز',p_name,Null) AS B1,
    IIF(s_p = 'منجز منشور',p_name,Null) AS C1,
    IIF(s_p = 'مخطط',p_name,Null) AS D1
    FROM manuscript
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN colldet
    ON  manuscript.coll_name = colldet.college return records?  If not,, what is the error?

Comment: Duplicate rows are returned

Comment: I think `DISTINCT` need a subquery in the `select` clause to prevent duplicates, but I don't know how to do this query

Comment: If you could post sample duplicate records returned from the inner SELECT DISTINCT it would be helpful to find what's going on.  Or, give a specific description of what you are trying to accomplish with the overall query.  Perhaps there is a better way to get what you need.